# How to pass multiple parameters in a value attribute and put them in an associative array in the name attribute?

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to put multiple parameters in a value attribute and put them in an associative array in the name attribute?

Should I do this differently?

I'm trying to implement this with a bootstrap custom select https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

[image: custom select]

I need to pass the collaborator_id and card_id (card_id is assigned above in the code)see code below

```
<form action="card/add_participant" method="POST">
    <label for="add_participant">Add participant</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select name="participantAndCard[]" class="custom-select" id="add_participant">
            <option selected>Choose participant</option>
            <?php foreach ($collab as $c) : ?>
                <option value="collaborator_id => <?=$c->id?>, card_id => <?=$card->id ?> "><?= $c->full_name ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

On the server-side

```
public function add_participant(){
   $participantAndCard = $_POST['participantAndCard'];
   var_dump($participantAndCard);
  }
```

I'm getting an array with a string inside.

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(37) "collaborator_id => 33, card_id => 73 " }
```

What am I doing wrong?
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't want to pass the select input as an array with `participantAndCard[]` just use `participantAndCard`:

```
<select name="participantAndCard" class="custom-select" id="add_participant">
```

Then create an array and encode it as JSON:

```
<option value='<?= json_encode(['collaborator_id'=>$c->id, 'card_id'=>$card->id]); ?>'><?= $c->full_name ?></option>
```

Then decode in PHP:

```
$participantAndCard = json_decode($_POST['participantAndCard'], true);
```

If for whatever reason you need `participantAndCard` to be an array, then use the `participantAndCard[]` name in the select and then loop in PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['participantAndCard'] as $value) {
    $participantAndCard[] = json_decode($value, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly, it didn't work
`Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/prwb_2021_c01/controller/ControllerCard.php on line 293
NULL`

Comment: I changed to participantAndCard, there's no warning anymore but the output is NULL

Comment: Sorry, quote problem in the option.  Copy it again.  I changed the `"` to `'`.

Comment: Yes! exactly! it's working, thank you very much :D